# Mnemonic suffixes for x86-64 assembly for AT&T syntax

Tags: assembly, x86-64, intel

I'm trying to understand suffixes used for the AT&T syntax for the x64 assembly used for instruction mnemonics.

For regular cases:

```
'b',     // 8_bit
'w',     // 16_bit
'l',     // 32_bit
'q',     // 64_bit
't',     // 80_bit
```

Examples: Intel vs AT&T:

```
inc word ptr [rbx]        incw   (%rbx)
inc dword ptr [rbx]       incl   (%rbx)
inc qword ptr [rbx]       incq   (%rbx)
```

But then for floating-point instructions, it's different:

```
L'b',     // 8_bit
L'w',     // 16_bit
L's',     // 32_bit
L'l',     // 64_bit
L't',     // 80_bit
```

If so, then why does the GCC compiler give me this:

```
fiadd word ptr [rcx]           fiadds (%rcx)
fiadd dword ptr [rcx]          fiaddl (%rcx)
```

Can some confirm if I'm right, or correct me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right: [Operation suffixes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GNU_assembly_syntax#Operation_Suffixes) on wikibooks.